# Why we can not pass integer literal as argument to method with byte as formal parameter

Tags: java

**Query 1:**

```
byte a = 0; // int to byte implicit conversion happens, correct!, no CTE [compile time error]
setByte(0); // CTE!, why ? implicit conversion do not happen here 
void setByte(byte b){}
```

**Query 2:**

```
byte b_byte = 128 - 1; // integer literal computation results to 127 int which implicitly casts to byte and as 127 is in range of byte so no CTE, Correct!
int a_int = 2147483647; // in range of int, so no CTE
int b_int = 2147483648 - 1; // still in range of int but CTE, why ?
```

please explain, also point to JLS section where theses rules are defined.

Comment: You can't pass a `long` to a method that wants an `int`, but you can pass a method that wants a `long` an `int`, because `long` is wider than `int`. [5.1 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Comment: All downcasting is explicit. Bare integers are treated as `int`s and can be upcast implicitly to a `long` or `double` as needed. Downcasts are different. You need to explicitly state the type or cast.

Comment: are you sure `2147483648` is in the range of `int`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger it is not, it's just one over `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, [Assignment Conversions, JLS 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) covers what values can be assigned.

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the variable is of type `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

For `byte a = 0;` the constant expression is the `int` `0` which is narrowed to a `byte`.

Next, [Invocation Contexts, JLS 5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) covers what values can be passed to methods.

> *Neither strict nor loose invocation contexts include the implicit narrowing of integer constant expressions which is allowed in assignment contexts.*

Therefore, your code has a compiler error for the constant expression narrowing conversion that is disallowed in an invocation context (method call).

```
setByte(0); // no implicit narrowing conversion, even if it's a constant expression
void setByte(byte b){}
```

Your code `128 - 1` is a constant expression that is narrowed to a `byte`.

However, `2147483648 - 1` is disallowed because `2147483648` itself [is not a valid `int` literal, Section 3.10.1, "Integer Literals"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1).

> **It is a compile-time error if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator; or if a decimal literal of type int is larger than 2147483648 (2<sup>31</sup>)**.

If you really want to use an unnecessarily complicated expression to initialize an `int`, you can use a `long` literal to make the expression legal:

```
2147483648L - 1
```

but then you must explicitly cast the expression to an `int`; there is no implicit narrowing from anything wider than `int` to an `int`:

```
(int) (2147483648L - 1)
```

Strangely, you don't have to place parentheses around the expression so that the cast applies to the whole expression, although I strongly recommended to use parentheses for clarity.

```
(int) 2147483648L - 1  // It's 2147483647!
```

The `int` cast on the `long` literal, which is out of `int` range, will yield -2147483648, a valid `int` value.  Subtracting 1 here involves overflow in the negative direction, yielding the intended value of 2147483647.